# ASP.NET MVC FileResult is corrupting files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been trying to get my ASP.NET MVC website to export some data as an Excel file. For hours I thought that NPOI was just producing garbage so I switched over to EPPlus. I tested it in LINQPad and it created a proper working XLSX file, so I moved the code over to the MVC app. AGAIN, I get corrupted files. By chance I happened to look at the temp directory and saw that the file created by EPPlus is 3.87KB and works perfectly, but the `FileResult` is returning a file that's 6.42KB, which is corrupted. Why is this happening? I read somewhere that it was the server GZip compression causing it, so I turned it off, and it had no effect. Someone, please help me, I'm going out of my mind... Here's my code.

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult Excel(
    CenturyLinkOrderExcelQueryModel query) {
    var file = Manager.GetExcelFile(query); // FileInfo

    return File(file.FullName, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", query.FileName);
}
```

Comment: What is the type and value of file.FullName? Is it a byte array? Have you tried adding the proper file extension like ".xls" to the file name?

Comment: `file` is of type `FileInfo`, so no it's not a byte array. The path returned is correct, and with a proper extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned there's an issue with the `FileResult` and it's accompanying methods. I ended up "resolving" the issue by overriding the `Response` object:

```
[HttpGet]
public void Excel(
    CenturyLinkOrderExcelQueryModel query) {
    var file = Manager.GetExcelFile(query);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + query.FileName);
    Response.BinaryWrite(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName));
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `OpenRead` from `FileInfo` to get a file stream and see if that works.

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult Excel(CenturyLinkOrderExcelQueryModel query) {
    var file = Manager.GetExcelFile(query); // FileInfo
    var fileStream = file.OpenRead();
    return File(fileStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", query.FileName);
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. The file it spat out was 6.44KB, .02KB larger than the code I had up there before. Is it possible that it's adding response headers as part of the binary? It's the only information I can think of that would be present with the request.

Comment: Just for debugging do a check on the length of `fileStream` and see of it is the expected size of the file.

Comment: I did earlier, and it was the expected size, 3972 (or somewhere there, but it was the ~4KB file I was expecting).

Comment: It was the expected size when it was getting to the `return File(...)` line. Thereafter it is my belief that the framework was padding it somehow with something and sending back a file with an inflated size that couldn't be opened. I posted my answer as to how I "resolved" it below. As far as I'm concerned, this is a framework issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `FileStreamResult(fileStream, MIMEType)` to download the excel file the following way:

**Note: Does not work**

```
        //
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 512];
        int bytesRead;
        Response.BufferOutput = false;
        Response.ContentType = fileInDb.MIMEType;

        //Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", "3,339,911,168");
        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = fileInDb.FileName, // MIMEType does not replace extension (the extension is indispensable)
            Inline = false,
            Size = fileInDb.FileSizeInBytes,
            DispositionType = fileInDb.MIMEType
        };
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            Response.Flush(); // The remote host closed the connection -> type -> System.Web.HttpException
        }
        fileStream.Close();

        return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, fileInDb.MIMEType);
```

And when I open it it says:

`Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.`

and

`Errors were detected in file ....`

`Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.`

For me I had to do the download the file like this to solve the problem and download the excel file without issues:

**Note: This works**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Download(Guid? Id)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileFullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        Response.BufferOutput = false;
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        return File(fileStream, fileInDb.MIMEType); // works
        return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, fileInDb.MIMEType); // also works
    }
```